# What are XHR possible issues

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am wondering what issues can occur when sending/receiving an xhr (xmlhttprequest).

- The server can offline so that is an obvious issue
- Can an xhr request be lost (server is fine but request did not come through) ?
- Can multiple xhr request which are send in some order be 'handled' in a different order?
- Is it possible that the request gets corrupted?
- Is it possible that the request arrives more than once to the server?
- Maybe there are others that I do not really know about...

I guess some of these 'issues' are handled by the underlying network layer(s) but I do not really know which are and which should be handled by the application.

Thx

Comment: see this:http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call

Answer (score -1):

In theory it could be loads of things that could go wrong in the whole process of sending and receiving a ajax request. However the HTTP request can go wrong and give all these different responses [HTTP Error 
codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) 
For instance a request can timeout (408) but that could be caused by a problem with the clients network the server network or any connection in between. So you might need to ask yourself is the reason important why things go wrong or that is goes wrong and what kind within the HTTP-request error codes it belongs to?